# Min Max Regex for QtCore.QRegExp

Tags: regex, validation, qtcore, qregexp

What would be a proper syntax to write a regex expression that limits a user from entering only integer numbers between a range of: 15 and 764
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Regex is for pattern matching. You're not looking for any pattern - just input validation, so you should simply check that the input is in your range using `>,<,=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following regular expression

```
^(1[5-9]|[2-9]\d|[1-6]\d\d|7[0-5]\d|76[0-4])$
```

- `1[5-9]`: 15 ~ 19
- `[2-9]\d`: 20 ~ 99
- `[1-6]\d\d`: 100 ~ 699
- `7[0-5]\d`: 700 ~ 759
- `76[0-4]`: 760 ~ 764

Escape `\` if you use the pattern inside string literal.

```
"^(1[5-9]|[2-9]\\d|[1-6]\\d\\d|7[0-5]\\d|76[0-4])$"
```